# force pipenv to (re)install a package from github even if the version has not changed

Tags: python, github, pip, pipenv

I am developing a django-resuable-app ("common-functionality") and a django-project ("my-project") which uses that app.  These are stored in separate github repositories, and my-project references common-functionality as an editable dependency:

**Pipfile:**

```
common-functionality = {editable = true,git = "https://github.com/my-organization/common-functionality-users",ref = "master"}
```

How can I ensure that the *latest* version of common-functionality is installed any time I re-run `pipenv install`?

It seems that pipenv will only update dependencies if the version in "setup.py" changes.  Must I change that every time I push common-functionality to github?  Or is there some other way to solve this problem?

---

Actually, I am mistaken. Even if the version changes the latest code is not  re-installed from github.  Presumably, this is b/c nothing has changed in the "Pipfile.lock".  So the question remains: Is there a way to *force* pipenv to reinstall something even if it normally would not?

Answer (score 1):

For one, yes it's probably advisable to change the version number for each distinct version for reasons outside of the scope of this thread.

That said I'd recommend you simply `pipenv uninstall` followed by `pipenv install`. If you find yourself needing to do this more often you could use a simple bash script or alias to automate it.